# Magic squares as sums of permutation matrices

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, permutations

A magic square of size $n$ and sum $k$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with non-negative integer elements, whose rows and columns all sum to $k$. A permutation matrix is a magic square of sum $1$. Every magic square can be written as a sum of permutation matrices, in general not uniquely.

What is known about the problem of finding the number of ways a magic square can be written as a sum of permutation matrices? Are there available upper bounds, recurrence relations, algorithms?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but this is the same as studying integer points in (dilations of) the Birkhoff polytope.

Comment: @SamHopkins: the integer points correspond to the magic squares themselves. I don't see a useful connection with the number of ways to write a particular magic square as a sum of permutation matrices.